# Cleaning up a 3d scan. Help/advice please

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Could someone point me in the right direction please?
I'm trying to clean up this scan.
I've got pretty far with circle select and delete vertices, but I can't figure out how to delete all these weird lines without chopping massive holes in the bits I want to keep, It's all getting a bit messy and there's got to be an easier way.

I hoped I could just cut or delete them from the centerpoint all in one go, but I can't figure out how.

Any advice would be appreciated.

FYI - I have zero blender experience.

[image]

Comment: It's certainly possible but it's hard to tell just looking at the picture. Could you upload this model (or just troublesome part of it) to the: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: You should have a vertex or several vertices at the center, so if you delete those, you should get rid of all the lines. You can also try this: Press spacebar and type "Select Non Manifold". This should select all bad geometry and allow you to delete it.

Comment: @LukeD [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=4231" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/4231/) Does this help?

Comment: select non manifold just made loads of holes unfortunately. I had high hopes!

Comment: I got rid of all the lines by deleting the many many vertices at the center. I now have holes all over, but that's fixable. Thanks @HENDRIX

Comment: Also Select All and W > Remove Doubles. Then you can go to Mesh > Clean Up > Fill Holes and set number of sides to fill (press F6 to see this option).

Comment: next time, maybe you could try dissolving vertices.